# uncommon infinitive form

Tags: infinitives

I just have read on internet this headline:

> President Biden to defend Afghanistan policy in national address

I guess this 'subject+to+verb' structure is an uncommon form of the infinite to express something like: *an authority is going to talk soon defending the policy ('defending' in this case)*... , am I right? is this form only used in written formal English? the subject must be an authority? does the subject in this form always go without article?

Comment: Headlines frequently omit words to save space. Do **NOT** use them to learn English. Undoubtedly, the word “plans” was omitted. This headline is not grammatical.

Comment: @Juhasz thanks!! I hadn't seen that post :) how can I close this one?

Comment: I'm actually not sure.  There's some way that you can delete your own question, if you want.  Otherwise, I think a moderator can "close" it.  But that might require more close votes.  You probably don't need to take any action.